# "blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" when uploading file using nodejs and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

[enter image description here][1]I have error in cors "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" every time I try to send file from reactjs to nodejs. and I already added all the headers. and all the other request except the file uploading is working but a bit slow and I don't know why.
the other request is sending file from nodejs to reactjs and it's working slow.
I use aws lightsail bitnami server and i tried to change all the configurations but nothing changed.

so how can i fix it ?

this the headers I added

```
app.use((request, response, next) => {
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  response.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS"
  );
  response.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );

  next();
  console.log("did i passed it ?");
});
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

and i used also the cors package but it didn't work also

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors())
```

thanks in advance,

I tried adding the headers and I tried using cors package and changed the bitnami configurations

and here is my configurations for bitnami host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName timesheet.3f.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/timesheet.3f.com.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/timesheet.3f.com.key"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName timeapp.3f.com
  SSLEngine on
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3004/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3004/
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/timeapp.3f.com.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache /conf/timeapp.3f.com.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

this is the headers that sent from nodejs and reactjs. so all headers are included but still same error with cors.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9vXB.png

Comment: Did you try using the cors middleware? https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: yes i did like this app.use(cors()) and it didn't work

Comment: Can you paste the **full** error message?

Comment: this is the error message {Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://timesheet-api/add-file. (Reason: header ‘access-control-allow-headers’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response)}

Answer (score 0):

I think you instantiated cors wrong/wrong place. Try this:

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

// And here the rest of your app
```

Comment: thank you it worked but only when i deployed the backend on render.com and i still have the same issue on lightsail and i don't understand why